# Is using opto-couplers a good idea to switch in between two 80 pin connectors?

Tags: pcb, switches, connector, opto-isolator, eaglecad

I am trying to implement a switch between two 80 pin connector outputs so that I can activate the desired connector. There are high speed signals to be taken into account.

Is using opto-couplers a good idea? I am a beginner so any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Edit: I was advised to use opto-couplers. Maybe they have nothing to do with the solution.

To put in another way, I want to built an "intermediate circuit" which will enable me to switch between two 80 pin connectors (There are DisplayPort, UART, Audio and Control Signals going into each connector.) and pass the desired group of inputs to an 80 pin output connector.

Thanks.

Comment: the only information that you provided is `switching between two 80 pin connectors` ... there is no other info ... `high speed signals` is meaningless ... please think about what you are trying to do and add a clear description to your post ... **do not** use comments to add the info

Comment: 80x opto-couplers sounds like a lot. Why do you need the isolation?

Comment: @pjc50 it is unknown if the connectors are fully populated ... for all we know, the connectors could have only one wire

Comment: First make sure you can find fast enough optocouplers; most are pretty slow.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem to be honest. 160 optos is a lot of optos. Even for isolation ICs using other technologies that can fit 8 per IC, that's still 20 ICs.

Answer (score 1):

back in the days i saw a design that uses some 74LS244 TTL chips to switch between parallel ports connectors of a computer.

Looking into the 74LS244 data sheet will be self explanatory on how to make such circuit.

In any case you do not specify the signals you have to transfer...
If they are analog signals maybe some 4066 could be used to perform the same action.

Comment: look on the net for "Nuova Elettronica 186" magazine, you find it easy online (pdf) and look at "pag 2 Commutatore per ottenere 2 uscite parallele" the magazine is in Italian but schematic it is universal to understand.

Comment: Thanks a lot @gino